# XLConnect is loaded automatically when I start R session

Tags: r, xlconnect

I got a problem with the R package "XLConnect".

Every time I open R, this package is automatically loaded.

So I thought it had been included in the default packages for some strange reason, and I wrote like this:

getOption('defaultPackages')
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"

It does not appear in the default packages; now I really don't know what to do.

I ask for a help.

Comment: Did you change the Rprofile.site file?

Comment: No, I don't think so.
The latest function I had used is saveWorkbook after writing to Excel with writeWorksheet function.

Comment: Check the file: ...\R\etc\Rprofile.site

Comment: Are you certain you didn't `source` some of the functions in the package, thus placing them in your saved environment?  Make sure that `search` returns `XLConnect` as one of the loaded packages.

Comment: Are you restoring your workspace? If you are, don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem and the cause was a variable called `.required` in the "default workspace". That is, when you start R, it loads a workspace which on Windows could be, e.g., .RData file in "My documents" or some similar place.

Take a look at `ls(all=TRUE)` -- to list all variables, even those starting with period.

If you see `.required` there, and `.required` contains something like "XLConnect" then you've (probably by chance) told R to load XLConnect every time this workspace is loaded. Remove this variable

```
rm(.required)
```

.. and save the workspace

```
q("yes")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a workbook object using XLConnect and then save the workspace, the saved object in .RData triggers the loading of the XLConnect and XLConnectJars packages upon subsequent startups. Removing the object with rm() and then saving the workspace solves this problem.